# Why does my furnace stop unless we remove and replace the inspection panel?

Tags: heating

Furnace keeps stopping! What we do to restart is remove inspection panels, the combustion air blower ia always running and feels hot. Anyway we put panels back on and it works till next time. Please help

Comment: Get a different repairman who knows what he's doing.   But if you want any help here, you need to post the furnace type and  model, and what the repair man did and what he said was wrong.

Comment: Easier said than done, this home is 50 mile away from and bigger town. One flashing yellow lite. Our choices are none..

Comment: Yes -- we need to know what make and model the thing is, otherwise we can't even start...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the high limit might be tripping.  There are many causes for this, though faulty limit switch and/or dirty filters are the most common.

removing the access panel likely opens the door switch, so the unit is reset when the panel is put back in place.

Check for dirty filters, blocked/obstructed/closed return air vents, blocked/obstructed/closed registers. If you have the tools and knowledge to do so, inspect the high limit switch.

Comment: Older home in country, has older fireplace. It has 3 big knobs to turn. One is at top in the middle, it controls flew other two are located in lower corners, my question is what are the for? It does have a blower , small knob controls fan speed. We turn the big knobs but notice no change. Help